# How do I create a new dataframe by selecting rows (from a different dataframe) with specific column parameters?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, rank

I have a dataframe 'rank' of 100 students by 10 different 'region': A,B,C...H,I,J and 3 different 'eyecolor': X,Y,Z. How could I create a new dataframe with top 30 ranking students but with predetermined % representation from each of the following columns in Python:

for 'region', 15% of A, 5% of B and 10% of C ... J
for 'eyecolor', 25% of X, 60% of Y and 15% of Z

[original_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC8XU.png)

Comment: Hello, it is hard to picture out your problem. Please add a snippet of the code you tried so far. And a shot of your expected output.

Comment: also add a snippet of your input data frame. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example